# Adding array entries to existing JSON document from plain text input

Tags: shell-script, shell, json

I have a situation where i have output of one command, like this,

```
192.168.1.84
192.168.1.85
```

i want to use this, and make changes in another file, i.e add this ip addresses one after another like in this form. Below the **ResourceRecordSet** line.

```
ubuntu@kops:/mujahid$ cat change-resource-record-sets.json
{
    "Comment": "Update record to reflect new IP address of home router",
    "Changes": [
        {
            "Action": "UPSERT",
            "ResourceRecordSet": {
                "Name": "testing.mak.online.",
                "Type": "A",
                "TTL": 60,
                "ResourceRecords": [
                    {
                        "Value": "192.168.1.84"
                    },
                    {
                        "Value": "192.168.1.5"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What should the values for `Action`, `Name`, `Type`, and `TTL` be in the new `Changes` array item? It would be better if you added the expected output to the question so that we don't have to guess what you mean.

Comment: all same as above, those are the default for my env.

Comment: see i want the exact above just want the ip address to be added from the previous cmd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a proper JSON from the list of IP-addresses generated by `somecommand`, using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
somecommand | jq -Rs '{
  Comment: "Update record to reflect new IP address of home router",
  Changes: [ {
      Action: "UPSERT",
      ResourceRecordSet: {
        Name: "testing.mak.online.",
        Type: "A",
        TTL: 60,
        ResourceRecords: split("\n")|.[0:-1]|map({Value:.})
     } } ] }'
```

This results in

```
{
  "Comment": "Update record to reflect new IP address of home router",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "UPSERT",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "testing.mak.online.",
        "Type": "A",
        "TTL": 60,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "192.168.1.84"
          },
          {
            "Value": "192.168.1.85"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

given that `somecommand` outputs

```
192.168.1.84
192.168.1.85
```

Comment: hey! it worked, (partially) it perfectly created a json format,, but my requirement is to add the ip address below the `ResourceRecords:` which is already in the file, i have re added entire file above..

Comment: @Mohd See updated answer.

Comment: i checked with ur provided answer, although it works, but its not completely same..its missing the starting bracket with comment line.

Comment: @Mohd I think I have been misunderstanding you the whole time. You want to _create_ that JSON document? It does not already exist? I thought you wanted to _update_ it with new IP-addresses... Can you confirm this please, and it will be _easy_ to fix.

Comment: sorrry for misunderstanding, initially i only wanted the ip part, but later u provided a wonderful answer to create the entire file, so now i request u help me create this entire file , which i have pasted in my original questiion. so that i can directly use it to update my records

Comment: @Mohd Ok, see updated answer.

Answer (score -2):

You could store your input in a array and output everything with looping over it.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=' '
ARR=($@)
        for i in "${ARR[@]}"
        do
        echo $i >>/output/file.txt
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

This Script will output all you input line by line.

example call: `thisscript.sh $(command that generates your IP's)`

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to `somecommand >>/output/file.txt`

Comment: no, because 'some command >>/file' will write the commands output to the file in original format. My small script can handle the format input by changing the IFS env variable and outputs a line for any item.

Comment: Um... The output of the command is one IP address per line, so it's actually _exactly_ equivalent to just appending the output of the command to the end of the file. Also, the task is to insert these IP addresses into a JSON document in a particular format.